# How to prevent keyboard left press when focus is on the last element of the horizontal list

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a tv application and I want to prevent flutter focus system from changing focus when current focus is on the last element of a horizontal list and also showing focus border on the item.

Below code is the last element of a horizontal list and it's a button that when it gains focus, it shows a white border around the button and every thing is good,
but if the user presses the left arrow key, the focus goes some where else on other items of the page.

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: onMoreBtnTap,
  style: ButtonStyle(
    side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide?>((state) {
      if (state.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
        return const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3);
      }
      return null;
    }),
  ),
  child: const Text("Show More"),
)
```

I want to prevent this behavior and when focus is on the last item, it should stay there even if left arrow is pressed.

I also tried using `Focus` widget as the parent of this button to handle key events, but it gets another problem and it can not show the border and button press events:

```
Focus(
  onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
    if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {
      //This prevents left press, but button does not gain focus and FocusBorder
      return KeyEventResult.handled;
    }
    return KeyEventResult.ignored;
  },
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: onMoreBtnTap,
    style: ButtonStyle(
      side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide?>((state) {
        if (state.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
          return const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3);
        }
        return null;
      }),
    ),
    child: const Text("Show More"),
  ),
)
```

I added sample code to run [here](https://github.com/xzghx/tv_lists)

This is [screen record](https://github.com/xzghx/tv_lists/blob/main/README.md) of current behavior, pressing left keyboard button on the last element makes focus to jumps to next row's third item.

Comment: Please add a code snippet with the reproducible scenario.

Comment: @Hamed I added a link to the code.

Comment: Hello
I checked your sample code, but I couldn't reproduce your issue.
what do you mean by the left arrow? I don't see any soft keyboard in your sample code!
Can you please mention some steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Taleb if you run the code in emulator, you can select items with laptop's arrow keys. I added a small screen record, if you check it you can see that when focused item is the last item which is a button, when I press left arrow one more, the focus (highlighted with purple color) goes to the bottom list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle logical keyboard shortcuts by bellow code:

```
CallbackShortcuts(
      bindings: {
        const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft): () {
          if (controller.offset.toInt() == _itemsCount) {
            return;
          } else {
            Focus.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
        },
      },
    child: yourWidget(),
    );
```

I looked at your code and fixed your code like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('fa', ''),
        // Locale('en', ''),
      ],
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Focus(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          cacheExtent: 1000,
          // controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                  HorizontalList(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HorizontalList extends StatelessWidget {
  final int _itemsCount = 9;
  final AutoScrollController controller = AutoScrollController(
      //add this for advanced viewport boundary. e.g. SafeArea
      viewportBoundaryGetter: () => const Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
      //choose vertical/horizontal
      axis: Axis.horizontal,
      //this given value will bring the scroll offset to the nearest position in fixed row height case.
      //for variable row height case, you can still set the average height, it will try to get to the relatively closer offset
      //and then start searching.
      suggestedRowHeight: 200);

  HorizontalList({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CallbackShortcuts(
      bindings: {
        const SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft): () {
          if (controller.offset.toInt() == _itemsCount) {
            return;
          } else {
            Focus.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
        },
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _itemsCount + 1,
          //+1 for moreBtn
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: controller,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == _itemsCount) {
              return const Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  MoreBtn(),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return AutoScrollTag(
                key: ValueKey(index),
                controller: controller,
                index: index,
                child: Child(controller, index),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Child extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final AutoScrollController controller;

  const Child(this.controller, this.index, {super.key});

  @override
  State<Child> createState() => _ChildState();
}

class _ChildState extends State<Child> {
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
        debugPrint("Index of item with focus is: ${widget.index} ");
        widget.controller.scrollToIndex(widget.index,
            preferPosition: AutoScrollPosition.middle);
      }
    });
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      focusNode: focusNode,
      focusColor: Colors.purple,
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.cyanAccent,
        child: Text('${widget.index}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MoreBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  const MoreBtn({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print('press');
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide?>((state) {
          if (state.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
            return const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 3);
          }
          return null;
        }),
      ),
      child: Focus(
          onKey: (FocusNode node, RawKeyEvent event) {
            print(event.logicalKey);
            if (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.arrowLeft) {
              print('me');
              return KeyEventResult.handled;
            }
            print('and me');
            return KeyEventResult.ignored;
          },
          child: const Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                'ShowMore',
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```